# Why is it called Three20? Any meaning?

Tags: three20

I'm very curious, why is it called Three20? I can't seems to find it anywhere. Haha.

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: Maybe because it takes 3 people to write twenty lines of code ? Haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...after the 320-pixel-wide screen of the iPhone

Comment: http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/